# Node JS Project with Grunt, produced js file has ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, webstorm

The error is this mess, except this is an automatically generated js file, so I have no real idea how I would go about fixing it.

"E:\Webstorm\WebStorm 2016.1.3\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" js\meditection.js
e:\Meditection\Meditection Portal\js\meditection.js:73865
})(window);
   ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined

```
at Object.__dirname.8 (e:\Meditection\Meditection Portal\js\meditection.js:73865:4)
at s (e:\Meditection\Meditection Portal\js\meditection.js:1:316)
at e:\Meditection\Meditection Portal\js\meditection.js:1:367
at Object.__dirname.9../angular (e:\Meditection\Meditection Portal\js\meditection.js:73869:1)
at s (e:\Meditection\Meditection Portal\js\meditection.js:1:316)
at e:\Meditection\Meditection Portal\js\meditection.js:1:367
at Object.__dirname.22.angular (e:\Meditection\Meditection Portal\js\meditection.js:76783:1)
at s (e:\Meditection\Meditection Portal\js\meditection.js:1:316)
at e (e:\Meditection\Meditection Portal\js\meditection.js:1:487)
at Object.<anonymous> (e:\Meditection\Meditection Portal\js\meditection.js:1:505)
```

My html file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html layout-fill>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="./js/meditection.js"></script>
    <link href="./css/meditection.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Meditection</title>
</head>
    <body ng-app="med.landing" ui-view layout-fill></body>
</html>
```

Which seems to be entering the js file and executing it hence the error, but when I try to access the localhost where it's hosted, I get

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

So my question is what am I doing wrong? This honestly was working a little while back and I rebased my code, so it's probably got some silly config problem.

Thanks for any help in advance <3

Comment: Just because it's automatically generated, there's no reason you can't include the part where it throws the error.

Comment: So far the code block that throws the error is about 2k lines of code, but ends in   
jqLite(window.document).ready(function() {
    angularInit(window.document, bootstrap);
  });

})(window);

Comment: Are you sure you should use this file in a node.js enviroment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you're using is not designed for a node.js enviroment.

Node doesn't have a wndow object automatically, neither does Node apps have a document attached to them.

Comment: Makes sense, how would I go about using this file?

Comment: @Impulse I don't know where you get it from.

Comment: It's generated from this grunt script
grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell:tscompile', 'browserify:execute', 'cssmin:execute', 'uglify:execute']);

Comment: I don't know grunt, but something tells me, that the browserify module isn't for node.js

Comment: You're right, it's got something to do with execute, which apparently Runs selected files in a node.js child process.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue on windows but if you use Linux (Ubuntu) or mac, it works fine.

Grunt and Grunt plugins should be defined as devDependencies in your project's package.json. 
This will allow you to install all of your project's dependencies with a single command: npm install.

Comment: He doesn't have a problem with dependencies but rather with what grunt generates.